# How do I pass image from a network to another activity in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview displaying items from a json file online, the recyclerview also has a thumbnail image in each list item.

When I click on an item, it starts a new activity, how do I pass the thumbnail image fetched from the server to the new activity?

Here is my new activity code:

```
public class ItemModal extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_modal);

        TextView ItemNameV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView ItemDescV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView ItemPriceV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        ImageView ItemImageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String itemName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemName");
        String itemDesc = getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemDesc");
        String itemPrice = getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemPrice");
        String itemImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemImage");

        ItemNameV.setText(itemName);
        ItemDescV.setText(itemDesc);
        ItemPriceV.setText(itemPrice);
        ItemImageV.setId(Integer.parseInt(itemImage));
    }



}
```

Here is the Adapter Code:

```
public class AdapterItems extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataItems> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataItems current;
    int currentPos=0;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterItems(Context context, List<DataItems> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_items, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        DataItems current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.textItemName.setText(current.itemName);
        myHolder.textDesc.setText(current.itemDesc);
        myHolder.textPrice.setText("# " + current.price);
        myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

        // load image into imageview using glide
        Glide.with(context).load(current.itemImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .into(myHolder.ivItem);

    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView textItemName;
        ImageView ivItem;
        TextView textDesc;
        TextView textPrice;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textItemName);
            ivItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivItem);
            textDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
            textPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemModal.class);
            intent.putExtra("ItemName", textItemName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ItemImage", ivItem.getId());
            intent.putExtra("ItemDesc", textDesc.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ItemPrice", textPrice.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, textDesc.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code starting the new activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemModal.class);
            intent.putExtra("ItemName", textItemName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ItemImage", ivItem.getId());
            intent.putExtra("ItemDesc", textDesc.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ItemPrice", textPrice.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, textDesc.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Here I am just passing the id of the image which is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MyHolder class:**

```
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    String imageUrl;
    // .....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ...
        intent.putExtra("ItemImage", imageUrl);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Adapter onBindViewHolder:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // ...
    myHolder.imageUrl = current.itemImage;

}
```

**ItemModal class:**

```
public class ItemModal extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_modal);
        // ...
        ImageView ItemImageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String itemImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("ItemImage");
        Glide.with(this).load(itemImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .into(ItemImageV);

    }
}
```

Comment: How do I make it load from cache instead of network?

Comment: I think Glide already does this. Run your app ehile connected to android studio and look at the Network graph under Android monitor. When opening the activity it won't downlod anything new

Answer (score 1):

Change your on click function of view holder to like bellow

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
DataItems current=data.get(getAdapterPosition());
//getAdapterPosition() will return the clicked position
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemModal.class);
            intent.putExtra("ItemName", current.itemName);
            intent.putExtra("ItemImage", current.itemImage);
            intent.putExtra("ItemDesc", current.itemDesc);
            intent.putExtra("ItemPrice", "# " + current.price);
            Toast.makeText(context, textDesc.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Again you can use Glide to load image in itemMod.class activity
In Glide you can define wether it can load from cache or reload from network again
If you set from cache it won't use network to download image it will reuse the image which is downloaded for recyclerview

Comment: It should work because you are using the same while binding item data in onBindViewHolder

Comment: It crashes the app with some null pointer exception error or something

Comment: Can you send logcat